# how can i access diff-hl-flydiff-mode?

Tags: spacemacs

i'm using spacemacs with emacs 25.2.1 on windows8.1 64bit.
Description:
i want to use `diff-hl-flydiff-mode`.

Tried:
First i activated the spacemacs layer `version-control`. That works.

But how can i switch into the mode?
I can see Ediff and several commands, but nothing about `diff-hl-flydiff-mode`.
Do i need to install another package?

Answer (score 1):

[`diff-hl-flydiff-mode`](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl/blob/1d672dd0b2fc3ee723c77f227203c1acd80434a5/diff-hl-flydiff.el#L150) is a [global minor mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minor-Modes.html). You can activate it by adding:

```el
(diff-hl-flydiff-mode 1)
```

in your `init.el` so it applies whenever you start up Emacs. You can also turn it on or off interactively with by invoking `diff-hl-flydiff-mode` via `execute-extended-command` (`M-x` in vanilla Emacs).